# Am I Importing a SQLite3 C Function Correctly into C#

Tags: c#, c, import, dllimport

I am attempting to import a SQLite3 C function inside C# but I am unsure I have imported it correctly, ie, that the function parameter data types are correct and that the function is being used correctly? The function is being used to insert a images data(.png) into a Sqlite3 table.

This is the actual C implementation from the [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

```
int sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int n, void(*)(void*));
```

This is my import in C#:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_bind_blob")]
private static extern int sqlite3_bind_blob (IntPtr stmHandle, int iIndex, string iParam, int iBytes, int iOperation);
```

Usage of the SQLite3 function in C# (Note the function returns `21 - SQLITE_MISMATCH    20   /* Data type mismatch */`):

```
// blob is a byte[]
string query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable(lat, lon, image) VALUES({1}, {2}, ?1)";
sqlite3_prepare_v2 (_connection, query, query.Length, out stmHandle, IntPtr.Zero)
int res = sqlite3_bind_blob (stmHandle, 1, blob.ToString(), blob.Length, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Questions:
- Have I imported the sqlite3_bind_blob DLL function correctly with the correct parameter data types?
- Am I using the function correctly, ie, should I be converting the blob to a string and am I correctly obtaining the blob's (byte array's) length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_bind_blob", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int sqlite3_bind_blob (IntPtr stmHandle, int iIndex, byte[] iParam, int iBytes, IntPtr iOperation);
```

would be a better signature. Mainly because `System.String` is a reference to a class with unspecified internal structure, it's not even equivalent to `wchar_t**`.

With the corrected import, the invocation will look like

```
int res = sqlite3_bind_blob (stmHandle, 1, blob, blob.Length, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

and indeed, that's exactly what one of SQLite .NET wrappers do.