# Writing Image to SQLite Database always fails

Tags: sqlite, c++-cli

I am attempting to write a png to a SQLite3 database in C#. I have managed to correctly import the external DLL function `sqlite3_bind_blob` thanks to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182160/am-i-importing-a-sqlite3-c-function-correctly-into-c-sharp). But now I am getting an error when I write the image to my SQLite3 database.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? The function function `sqlite3_bind_blob` is returning the error `21 - SQLITE_MISMATCH 20 - Data type mismatch`. I am unsure what exactly is going wrong.

Heres my code:

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable(lat, lon, image) VALUES({0}, {1}, ?1);", lat, lon);

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2 (_connection, query, query.Length, out stmHandle, IntPtr.Zero) != SQLITE_OK) {
    IntPtr errorMsg = sqlite3_errmsg (_connection);
    throw new SqliteException (Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi (errorMsg));
}

IntPtr SQLITE_TRANSIENT = new IntPtr(-1); // Represents SQLITE_TRANSIENT
int res = sqlite3_bind_blob (stmHandle, 1, blob, blob.Length, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

// res always equals 21
```

From my debugging I know that the blob correctly contains valid png data because I can write it out to a file and open that file. I also know that the length of the blob is correct aswell. Maybe its my query string `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable(lat, lon, image) VALUES({0}, {1}, ?1);`?

Comment: These VALUES, `({0}, {1}, ?1)` look pretty odd to me - I'm not even sure SQLite understands the `{0}` style.  Could you try with `(?,?,?)` and bind the blob as `sqlite3_bind_blob (stmHandle, 3` (as it's the third positional parameter?

Comment: @fvu thanks for the comment. After I run string.Format() the string becomes `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable(lat, lon, image) VALUES(-33.458, 151.457, ?1);` so I think it should be ok for SQLite to handle. But maybe I should use ?0 instead? Not sure if its zero based index?

Comment: Keep it simple: just use `?,?,?` and bind the three parameters as 1 2 3, as described in the doc.

Comment: What type is blob? Also, what is the schema?

Comment: @fvu `{0}` and `{1}` are parameters to [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). This code is a big confusion between managed and unmanaged C++/CLI code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing managed with unmanaged code.

```
int sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int n, void(*)(void*));
```

You are providing managed `IntPtr blob` instead of unmanaged `const void*blob`.

You should be very sure about what you're doing when mixing managed with unmanaged code - and it seam you're not...

You may workaround this situation something like this (I don't have compiler right now) using:

```
unsafe { //this is for C#... probably not needed in C++/CLI
    int res = sqlite3_bind_blob (stmHandle, 1, (const void*) blob.ToPointer(), (int) blob.Length, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}
```

Anyways, unless you're pretty sure you need this stuff, I recommend you to go on managed [system.data.sqlite](/questions/tagged/system.data.sqlite) and abandon [SQLite3 CAPI](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).

Comment: Believe it or not, but System.Data.SQLite binds blobs like this: `UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_bind_blob(handle, index, blobData, blobData.Length, (IntPtr)(-1));`, where `blobData` has type `byte[]`. What's probably wrong with his code is that he passes `System.String` instead of `byte[]` to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`

Comment: System.Data.SQLite binds blobs using unsafe methods INTERNALLY. All user API is managed.